# Why can't I use server-side flow oauth tokens for an iOS app feed dialog?

Tags: facebook, authentication, mobile, oauth, dialog

I am working on a product which has both a desktop web site and a native iOS application. We are providing Facebook connect as a login option for our users in both contexts.

My intention was to share the same Facebook tokens via a secure JSON API for use in both contexts: when a user signs in on the web, the token is stored to our backend so that when the mobile client next runs, it can download the token and use it as well, and vice-versa. (* The detailed reasoning for this approach I explain at the end of the question, and is not essential to the question.)

**The problem: when the iOS client uses a token to preset a [feed dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/dialog/), if that token is generated by the web using the [server-side flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/), the dialog webview renders an error:**

**"An error occured with {my app name}. Please try again later."**

This is reliably reproducible:

1. Generate a new access token using the server-side flow. Make sure you request publish_actions permission since you'll be using the feed dialog.
2. Using an incognito browser window (to get an empty cookie jar), view the m.facebook.com page that the iOS feed dialog would render in its webview: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed?access_token=SERVER_SIDE_FLOW_ACCESS_TOKEN&app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&sdk=2&display=touch

Alternatively to #2 you could do all the work (which I have done already) of creating a dummy iOS app with the Facebook SDK, instantiating it correctly and presenting the dialog. It's just easier to go straight to the m.facebook.com feed URL for the purposes of reproducing the error.

If the token was generated by the auth flow initiated by the native Facebook iOS SDK instead of the server-side auth flow, the above feed url works perfectly fine, as expected.

Additionally, either token (mobile or server generated) works perfectly fine for posting feed items directly via the graph api. The problem is really just with the mobile feed dialog.

*Is Facebook intentionally disallowing server-side generated tokens from operating in mobile  feed dialog contexts?*

*Is this a bug with the feed dialog endpoint on m.facebook.com?*

*Or, hopefully, am I doing something wrong?*

---

Why do I want to share tokens?

- Since the offline_access permission is being removed, each client (web vs mobile) can benefit from having the other client refresh the same token when the user is active. This will lead to fewer instances of token expiry, and therefore fewer cases in which users must re-authenticate from scratch.
- Likewise, users are not asked so frequently to approve additional permissions, since each client can benefit from the other's permission augmentations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tokens you get from the server side auth are different from the ones on the client side (I look at iOS/Android as client).
The server tokens are long lived one (60 days) while the client ones are short lived (a few hours).

The server side flow adds another layer of security where your servers authenticate against the facebook servers, which is probably why you get a long lived token automatically when using this flow.

If you try the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) with an access token you will receive information about the token, such as the "origin" of the token.
For example a token generated from a client side auth (using js) has "Origin: Web".
That means that facebook indeed differentiate between tokens.

I'm not 100% sure about this, but from what you're saying it does sound like facebook is limiting the UI to the usage of client tokens and not server side ones, probably because the dialogs let the user do things without the need of the app to get permissions, and so if you have a 60 days token your app can then use it instead of the user and do things on his behalf with out having his permission.
I'm just guessing here.

What I would recommend you is to use the server token only on the server side, and let the iOS client handle his own token.
According to the [Handling Invalid and Expired Access Tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/) guide, it states:

> **iOS native applications**
>
> API errors are handled by the FBRequestDelegate interface. When you
>   detect an access token is invalid or has expired, your application
>   will need to multi-task over to the Facebook iOS app. Assuming the
>   user has not deauthorized your app, they will be immediately
>   multi-tasked back to your iOS application with a fresh, valid access
>   token.

Which means that you don't have to worry about the token getting expired on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the "origin" difference on the debugger. We also found this old FB bug report which was resolved as "by design:" https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/237660982956939

Comment: As I said, just use two different tokens, one for server one for client, I do the same with server and web/android clients. It even makes things easier since you don't have to sync the token between the server/client.